# How to list all the PIDs and names of all the runing processes

Tags: 12.04, command-line, ps

I know that there is this command :

```
ps aux
```

to get all info about the running processes .. but I need only the names and ids for these processes , is there any command can list the processes ids or names only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `o` argument instead of `u` to specify what you want to see:

```
ps axo pid,comm
```